# check unique email in mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, unique

Actually I am using mongodb with Express js framework and check the email exists with my custom code and now I want to check the email is existed in my collection or not with the package that can easy to use with the Express js framework.

```
If_exists(req,res,callback) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Auth = mongoose.model('Auth');
    Auth.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function (err1, user1) {
      if (user1) {
        var error = "email";
        var message = "Email already exists";
        callback(error,message);
        return;
      }
      else {
        var error = "";
        var message = "";
        callback(error,message);
        return;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add unique records in mongoose collection using attribute

> unique : true

in your model use like this 
**email:{type: String, unique: true},**

if you add like this then when you add new email and that email is already in collection then it's give you error

Comment: Thanks for the help but my question is to check existing emails for unique while inserting the new one.

Comment: Auth.count({email: email}, function (err, count){ 
    if(count>0){
        //document exists });
    }
}); 
findOne() will read + return the document if it exists On the other hand, find() just returns a cursor (or not) and only reads the data if you iterate over the cursor. So in our case, we're not iterating over the cursor, merely counting the results returned.